# Get private field values using Reflection API java

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws UnknownHostException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws IllegalAccessException 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Employee employee= new Employee();
        employee.setFirstname("Durga Dutt");
        employee.setLastname("Pandey");
        employee.setAge(28);
        employee.setSalary(100035);

        Class<?> cl= Class.forName("Employee");
        Field[] fields= cl.getDeclaredFields();

        for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(fields[i].get(employee));
        }

    }

}
```

Above program is returning values for public fields but not working on private member. I have declared getters and setters in my POJO class.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Here is the trick: fields[i].setAccessible(true);

Answer (score 4):

To get a value of a private field you should set it as accessible by using [`setAccessible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29).

[`getDeclaredFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) will allow you to see names of private fields, not the value.

Comment: +1, but after using the field, you should set it back to its original accessability status with `field.setAccessible(false)` (or generically: `field.setAccessible(statusThatWasQueriedBefore)`.